# how to handle exception in application level in xamarin form for windows 8.1

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a Windows 8.1 app using C# . and i want Handle Exception in Portable Class Libraries Project .

In general I'm having troubles handle Exception in App Level. I don't find useful documentation. It would be great if someone can help also recommend me good documentation.

Comment: I think you should do it in Windows 8.1 project. In Windows project from `App.xaml.cs` subscribe to `UnheandledException` event. But it's `partial` class, so you will not be able to stop debug in breakpoint. And probably it will work only in release mode.

Comment: thanks can you send any sample application code

Comment: http://www.markermetro.com/2013/01/technical/handling-unhandled-exceptions-with-asyncawait-on-windows-8-and-windows-phone-8/